# How to display customized output based on field values

Tags: javascript, html, css

So my aim is to create a pop up modal where one could click to enter their regional school code in a text or number field to see if they are eligible for the files posted or not.

for example, if your code is 11002, you should get the ***recommended message*** else the *apology message* also I would like to have a button that can prompt user to go back and enter a new code if the last one is not accepted. This should all be on the same page.

Below is my code so far but I wish to display the result in a span as plain text not as in a field.

```
<style>
#result {
  width: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
  float: right;
}
</style>

<script>
function locationlookup() {
  var result = document.getElementById("areacode").value;
  var schooling;
  if (result == 11002) {
    schooling = "Great! Your school is eligible for this course";
  } else if (result == 11003) {
    schooling = "Great! Your school is eligible for this course";
  } else if (result == 11004) {
    schooling = "Your school is eligible but you need good conduct certificate";
  } else {
    schooling = "Sorry. we currently do not serve in your entered location";
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = schooling;
}
</script>

  <table  align="center">
      <tr>
        <th>School Area code: <input type="text" name="areacode" id="areacode" >
          <button onclick="locationlookup()" id="btn1">Lookup</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="text" name="result" id="result" readonly></th>
        <!-- I wish to change the above field to a span so no limitations. but stuff don't 
work for me -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#areacode")
const span = document.querySelector("#result")
const btn = document.querySelector("#btnTryAgain")

function locationlookup() {
  const result = input.value;
  let schooling;
  let results = [11002, 11003, 11004]
  if (results.includes(Number(result))) { 
    schooling = "Great! Your school is eligible for this course" 
  } else {
    schooling = "Sorry. we currently do not serve in your entered location"
    btn.classList.toggle('hideBtn')
  }
  span.innerText = schooling;
}

function tryAgain() {
  input.value = ''
  span.innerText = '';
  btn.classList.toggle('hideBtn')
  input.focus()
}
```

```css
#result {
  width: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
  float: right;
}
.hideBtn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>School Area code: <input type="text" name="areacode" id="areacode" >
      <button onclick="locationlookup()" id="btn1">Lookup</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <span id="result"></span>
      <button onclick="tryAgain()" id="btnTryAgain" class="hideBtn btn">Try again</button>
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code work's here but when I copy it over to my wordpress platform it doesn't. I tried running it basically with notepad and my chrome browser but it doesn't display the output.

Comment: No error messages. However I found another way around from patching with trial and errors using a partial code that was meant for some other problem. I will post shortly

Comment: Nice, why do you uncheck my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

So I found the below walk around to the problem which is quite handy but I will like to use that of Nikola if it finally works.
here is the code.

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
function locationlookup() {
    var result = document.getElementById("areacode").value;
    var locality;
    if (result == 11002) {
        locality = "Great! Your school is eligible for this course";
    } else if (result == 11003) {
        locality = "Great! Your school is eligible for this course";
    } else if (result == 11004) {
        locality = "Your school is eligible but you need good conduct certificate and more whatever text for the coding";
    } else {
        locality = "Sorry. we currently do not serve in your entered location";
    }


    const el = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]');
    el.addEventListener('input', () => console.log(el.textContent));
    el.textContent = locality;
}
```

```css
/* Button used to open the contact form - fixed at the bottom of the page */
.open-button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}
.spanishly3 {
        text-align: left;
        }
.spanishly2 {
        float: right;
    }
.bold2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    }
.spanishly3:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: url("icon.png") no-repeat;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 6px 0 0;
}


/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  /*bottom: 50%;*/
  right: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  z-index: 9;
}

/* Add styles to the form container */
.form-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
.form-container input[type=text], .form-container input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* When the inputs get focus, do something */
.form-container input[type=text]:focus, .form-container input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for the submit/login button */
.form-container .btn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

/* Add a red background color to the cancel button */
.form-container .cancel {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Add some hover effects to buttons */
.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

    div[contenteditable] {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()"><div class="spanishly2"><span class="spanishly3" style="align: left;">hello</span><p><b class="bold2">Select Your Address</b></p></div></button>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form action="/action_page.php" class="form-container">
  

Area code: <input type="text" name="areacode" id="areacode" placeholder="00000">
        <button onclick="locationlookup()" id="btn1">Lookup</button>

   <div contenteditable></div>

<p><i>or login to set/use your location</i></p>
<br>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn">Login</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
    <a href="chrome://settings/addresses" target="_blank">Manage addresses</a>

  </form>
</div>
```